# Why does `tf.data.Dataset.map` run only once?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I have been digging around. Still baffled me, I can't find clear explanation anywhere.

```py
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1]*20))
dataset1 = (dataset1
            .batch(4)
            .map(lambda x: x+random.randint(0,20)))

for batch in iter(dataset1):
  print(batch)
```

```
tf.Tensor([21 21 21 21], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([21 21 21 21], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([21 21 21 21], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([21 21 21 21], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([21 21 21 21], shape=(4,), dtype=int32)
```

I expect `.map` to behave like a **normal** functional `map`. Which, it supposed to apply a function to each element. It feels like some of my assumptions are totally off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `tf.random` module, because native python will only generate numbers
once

```py
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1]*20))
dataset1 = (dataset1
            .batch(4)
            .map(lambda x: x+tf.random.uniform((), 0, 20, tf.int32)))

for batch in iter(dataset1):
    print(batch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any tensorflow declaration is a declaration of an execution graph, what must be realy run extra via `sess = tf.Session() , sess.run(object) , sess.run(dataset1` ) in your case

Comment: Does that apply to Tensorflow2 with eager execution on by default?

Comment: dkn, but you see here its not executed.

Comment: I believe it does. I have tried to replace that lambda with a print statement. It does run and print out my test message. The point is that it does just once, not for every element or even each batch.

Comment: use some tf.random function. the answer is in your question => for some reason lambda runs ones :D